# How to set the value of a column based on the ID of the same row?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a database table that looks like this:

[image]

I want to input a name and a parity (ODD or EVEN). For example:

On my first input with ID 1, the field parity should automatically be `ODD`. On the next input and the parity field should automatically be `EVEN`. My Question is how to write code in the controller to make happen work?

This is my controller:

```
    $usertest = new UserTest;
    $usertest->name = $request->name;
    $usertest->parity = 'ODD' or 'EVEN';
    $usertest->save();
```

I don't know how to implement the automatic input into the field parity (ODD or EVEN) based on the ID.

Thanks in advance those who answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

You first get the last inserted id and icrement it by 1 and the check if the incremented id is ODD Or EVEN based on that you can insert data:

```
$lastId = DB::table('UserTest')->latest('id')->first(); // i.e $lastId = 10
$lastId++; // i.e $lastId = 11

// check if $lastID (i.e 11) for the ODD or EVEN
$usertest->name = $request->name;
$usertest->parity = ($lastId % 2 == 0) ? 'EVEN' : 'ODD';
$usertest->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save first your `UserTest` object and then after you get id. By using that Id you can update that field is parity is even or odd.

Try as below.

```
$usertest = new UserTest;
$usertest->name = $request->name;
$usertest->save();


UserTest::find($usertest->id)->update(['parity' => ($usertest->id % 2 == 0) ? 'EVEN' : 'ODD']);
```

**Note :** Make sure your parity field default value is null.